# Nginx return file when it's in cache/check if file exists in cache

Tags: caching, nginx

I'm using ngnix as reverse proxy server. There is a situation when backend server is down and I know about it. Thus I'm adding 'Check-Cache' header to request and what I want to do is get the file when it is in cache, and when it is not just return error page. I don't want to pass the request to the backend.

Scenario

```
$ curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" 0/images/2.jpg -H'Host: example.com'
200
$ pkill -9 backend_server
$ curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" 0/images/2.jpg -H'Host: example.com' -H'Check-Cache: true'
404 <-- I want to 200 here
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;

    underscores_in_headers on;
    proxy_cache_purge on;

    location / {
        error_page 599 = @jail;
        recursive_error_pages on;

        if ($http_check_cache = "true") {
            return 599;
        }

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache my-cache;
        proxy_cache_valid  200 302  10m;
        proxy_cache_valid  404      1m;
        proxy_cache_key    $uri$is_args$args;
    }

    location @jail {
        # try_files ??
        # proxy_cache_key (If i can get it i can use try_files)
        # what other solution...
        return 404;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, maybe not so beautiful solution but upstream can be used with one server makred as down.

```
http {
upstream backend-jail {
    server 0.0.0.0 down;
}

server {
    listen      80;

    underscores_in_headers on;

    recursive_error_pages on;
    error_page 597 = @jail;

    location / {
        if ($http_x_backend_down = "1") {
            return 597;
        }
        ########
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;             
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_cache my-cache;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 302  1h;
        proxy_cache_valid 404      1m;
        proxy_cache_key    $uri$is_args$args;
    }

    location @jail {
        # dont need to log error about 'no live upstreams'
        error_log /dev/null crit;

        # backend-jail always return 502, want 404 to be returned.
        error_page 502 =404 /;

        proxy_pass http://backend-jail;
    }
}
}
```